# Number spiral in C, code not working

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to make a spiral in  C using a 2D matrix, such as the one shown below:

[image]

This is the code that I worked out. But it keeps going into an infinite loop. I can't seem to get an output. Can anyone tell me what mistake I'm making in this logic?

And I know its pretty cumbersome, but the assignment is to get the output for any "n" dimensional array, and we need to use all the row_left,row_right, etc variables, as they're given in the question.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int array[6][6]={1},dim,row_right=0,row_left=dim-1,col_up=0,col_down=dim-1;
    int i,j,num,cnt;

    printf("Enter the dimensions of 2D array:\n");
    scanf("%d",&dim);

    num=dim*dim;
    cnt=0;

    while(cnt!=num)
    {
        for(j=col_up;j<=col_down;j++)
        {   
            if(j=0) 
                array[row_right][j]=1;
            else
                array[row_right][j]=array[row_right][j-1]+1;
        }
        for(i=row_right+1;i<=row_left;i++)
            array[i][col_down]=array[i-1][col_down]+1;

        for(j=col_down-1;j>=col_up;j--)
            array[row_left][j]=array[row_left][j+1]+1;

        for(i=row_left-1;i>row_right;i--)
            array[i][col_up]=array[i+1][col_up]+1;

        row_right++;
        row_left--;
        col_up++;
        col_down--;
        cnt++;
    }

    for(i=0;i<dim;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<dim;j++)
            printf("%d\t",array[i][j]);

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indent your code please. This may help you to find problem by yourself.

Comment: Try entering the smallest possible dimensions, and run it in a debugger to see what's happening.

Comment: row_right and col_down can't be initialized using dim until dim is given a value.

Comment: You prompt the user for the dimensions, but somehow want to get the job done using a _fixed size array_? `array[6][6]` should be _at least_ a VLA

Comment: Is there a formula to get the value at any position, without calculating previous ones?

Comment: @self.: Yes, there is: outer numbers are mirrored by themselves + 10 (left 2nd line from bottom == 17, right 2nd from top is 7). The closer the numbers get, the smaller the _"step"_, converging on 36 (that's where it gets tricky). Just look for any of the patterns in the diagonals, and pick the one you find easy to translate into code

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I was looking for the general formula. I think there are more than one for one matrix.

Comment: @self.: In that case [check rosettacode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Spiral_matrix#C)

Comment: @elias I need to initialize it with a fixed dimension array right. .?

Comment: @AnujaPL: Why would that be required? A VLA, or even dynamically allocated memory would work, too... it'll require some more work on your part, though :P

Answer (score 2):

```
if(j=0)
```

is almost surely wrong. This sets j to zero and always evaluates to a false condition. The correct condition uses `j == 0`.

Also, the code uses the variable `dim` before it is read by `scanf`.

Comment: yeah.. that was a pretty silly error.. I shouldv'e indented it too.. :/ .. next tym (y)

Comment: @AnujaPL : compare `if(j=0)` to `if (j = 0)`, it's the same thing but the second version is more readable and you would probably have seen the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to initialize the variable `dim`. That is used in following line :

```
int array[6][6]={1},dim,row_right=0,row_left=dim-1,col_up=0,col_down=dim-1;
```

With correctly formatted code you probably would have seen this.

Comment: @AnujaPL : And format your code correctly... it is unreadable.